# How to use predicate in c# to avoid and or conditions

Tags: c#, linq

```
var queryableDcbooking = (from t in dcBookingEntities.Bookings
  join t1 in dcBookingEntities.BookingWorkFlowStatusMasters on t.BookingWorkFlowStatusId equals t1.BookingWorkFlowStatusId
  join t2 in dcBookingEntities.StatusMasters on t.StatusId equals t2.StatusId
  join t3 in dcBookingEntities.PNBStatusMasters on t.PNBStatusId equals t3.PNBStatusId into gj
  from pnb in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
  where (
  (paraName.ToLower() == Comparator.Bookingid && intSearch.Contains(t.BookingId))
  || (paraName.ToLower() == Comparator.Dccode && strSearch.Contains(t.DCMaster.DCCode))
  || (paraName.ToLower() == Comparator.Supplierid && intSearch.Contains(t.SupplierId))
  || (paraName.ToLower() == Comparator.Doorid && intSearch.Contains(t.DoorId))
  || (paraName.ToLower() == Comparator.Carrierid && intSearch.Contains(t.CarrierId))
  || (paraName.ToLower() == Comparator.Buyer && strSearch.Contains(t.Buyer))
  )
```

`paraName` is a search by `bookingId`, `dccode` string and `intSearch` contains multiple `bookingids`.

Can I avoid and/or conditions in this code using predicate in Linq query ?

Comment: You could refactor the condition into a method and reference that in the `where`. However you can´t get rid of all those checks if you have to make them. Linq won´t do anything magic for you, it´s just a technology. Your *business*-logic will still be the same.

Comment: Why you use `paraName.ToLower()` in the query and not once before the query?

Comment: thanks to reply.. but i not getting the how to write predicate for such condition can you help out something.

Comment: I am using that paraName.ToLower() is for putting condition on linq depends on what paraName is passing from client.if client  passes the booinkingid result search by booking entity

Comment: Create a `Dictionary<Comparator,Func<Booking,bool>>` and populate it with an expression for each Comparator. The expression should accept a booking and return a Boolean for the Where clause. The local variable `intsearch` will be moved to closure. You use `paraName` to pick a function from the dictionary. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just build the expressions in a method that determines the parameter to use:

```
private Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> GetExpression(string param, string searchTerm)
{
    switch (param)
    {
        case "bar":
            return f => f.Bar.Contains(searchTerm);
        case "baz":
            return f => f.Baz.Contains(searchTerm);
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then call it like that:

```
var bars = (from c in collection select c).Where(GetExpression(param, searchTerm));
```